# HashMap's Iterator to prevent concurrent modification

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap, concurrentmodification

The following piece of code, while executed by a single thread, throws a [`ConcurrentModificationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) on line 4:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("key1", "value1");
map.put("key2", "value2");
for (String key : map.keySet()) { // Here
    map.remove(key);
}
```

I couldn't find any `Map.iterator()` or `Map.mapIterator()` method on [`HashMap` Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).
What should I do?

Comment: Your question looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to do? For now it looks like you are trying to reinvent `map.crear()` method, or `map.keySet().clear()` or even `map.values().clear();`.

Comment: @Pshemo Having a much more complicated scenario, I preferred to write a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from scratch here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you guessed, you need an `iterator` for removing items during iteration. The way to do it with a `Map` is to iterate the `entrySet()` (or, alternatively, the `keySet()`, if you only need to evaluate the key):

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> entryIter = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String, String> entry = iter.next();
    iter.remove(); // Probably guard this by some condition?
}
```